# biber error from spaces in paths using addbibresource

Tags: biblatex, biber

Just dug into a paper I haven't edited in a while and I have unexpected bibliography issues.

I use Visual Studio Code to build a LaTeX document with Latex Workshop plugin and Mendeley references manager for my bibliography (via `biber`) - but I get the same behavior with TexMaker, or directly with `latexmk` at command line.

Generally Mendeley (on Win10) plays well keeping `my.bib` up to date, formatted correctly. Historically I've left default installation alone so it tends to wedge itself into directories with spaces, ex:

```
C:/Users/User Name/Documents/Mendeley Bibtex/my.bib
```

I'm using Biber with `biblatex`, so I add the `.bib` file this way:

```
\addbibresource{"C:/Users/User Name/Documents/Mendeley Bibtex/my.bib"}
```

... and all is usually well with the double-quotes (we expect both spaces in the path to be escaped). However, I now get an error that Biber can't find said file, to wit:

> ```
> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'C:/Users/User\ Name/Documents/Mendeley Bibtex/my.bib' for section 0       
> ERROR - Cannot find 'C:/Users/User\ Name/Documents/Mendeley Bibtex/my.bib'!
> ```

Which suggests that it's correctly managed `/User\ Name/`, then tripped up on the space in `/Mendeley Bibtex/` perhaps.

When I move `my.bib` directly into the directory with the latex files and redirect `\addbibresource` it finds it (though that would mean changing my Mendeley setup), so I wonder if this isn't some simple bug that has forgotten to escape the second space in a working path. Suggestions where to go looking?

Comment: It fails for me with one space too. Add an issue to the biber tracker. See e.g. https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/280 for a similar issue.

Comment: Report the bug at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues (but keep in mind that people who use spaces in file names deserve no sympathy).

Comment: I have reported the issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/308 since it came up again in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531020/35864. But please keep in mind that you should report issues like this yourself if you want them to get fixed. Open source software (and indeed any software) development relies on users reporting issues to the appropriate instances.

Answer (score 1):

Biber 2.14 has a bug that means that `.bib` files with spaces are not found on Windows and that files with more than two spaces are not correctly globbed, which means they can not be found on any OS.

This bug was reported in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/308 and resolved shortly afterwards. File names with spaces work fine with Biber 2.15.

**Update your TeX system and makes sure you have at least Biber 2.15 (and `biblatex` 3.15a) installed.**

If you are stuck with an older version of Biber that can't properly deal with spaces the only sound workaround is to use file names without spaces. That definitely used to be best practice since several command line tools have issues with spaces in file names. But in the LaTeX world most tools should now be able to deal with spaces just fine.