# Many problems with TexStudio bibliography!

Tags: bibliographies, errors, biber

Using current TexStudio (installed two days ago). I have set TexStudio configuration as follows: Build default bibliography is set to "Biber" and I have set Build & View (shortcut) to txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Essay 1.bib}
```

in Essay 1.bib

```
@InBook{Snowdon,
    author = {B. Snowdon and H. Vane},
    title = {Modern Macroeconomics: Its Origins, Development and Current State},
    chapter = {8},
    publisher = {Edward Elgar Pub},
    year = {2005},
}
@inbook{Palley,
    author = {Palley, Thomas I.},
    title = {The Emergence of Theoretical and Institutional Coherence in Post Keynesian Economics},
    booktitle = {Post Keynesian Economics: Debt, Distribution and the Macro Economy},
    date = {1996},
}
```

My problems:
Problem 1:

```
Process started: biber.exe "Essay 1"

INFO - This is Biber 2.14
INFO - Logfile is 'Essay 1.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Essay 1.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'Essay 1.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'Essay 1.bib' to Essay\ 1.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Essay\ 1.bib' for section 0

ERROR - Cannot find 'Essay\ 1.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

I get this error, which I have no idea how to fix, since it seems to be a problem it is generating on its own: it's "globbing" data source into Essay\ 1.bib and then can't find the thing it just made?

Problem 2:
The in line citations look like this:

```
\cite[p.454]{Snowdon}
\cite[p.9]{Palley}
```

The outcome of these in the pdf generated do not include the [options] and are printed in bold. How do I get my full citation and not in bold?

I'm a beginner, and this is beyond frustrating. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it's impossible to test disconnected fragments rather than a real test document but having spaces in the filename makes everything a lot more complicated so I would not do that.

Comment: Oh dear god, that was all it needed. I removed the space and everything is totally fine. Thank you.

Comment: @Jessica Welcome to tex.sx! Don't worry, the learning curve is a bit steep at first, but once you give in to the inevitable TeX addiction coming your way it'll get easier :)

Comment: If only you'd seen this really constructive comment from a few years ago https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129 :-)

Comment: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/308